# Extending $\mathbb Q$ with different roots of $x^5-15$ results in different fields.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Problem: Let $a,b$ be 2 different roots of $x^5-15$ over $\mathbb C$, show that $\mathbb Q(a) \neq \mathbb Q(b)$ (as subfields of $\mathbb C$).

My attempt: I don't know how to show this, obviously it suffices to show $a$ is the only root in $\mathbb Q(a)$. It's not a general truth that different roots of an irreducable polynomial result in different fields so it must be a special property of $x^5-15$, in particular the free coefficient (since the assertion is not true for $x^5-1$) . I also know the fields are ring-isomorphic but since I don't know all the isomorphisms from $\mathbb Q(a)$ to itself that does not help much either. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: To start off: it's obvious if $a$ is the one real root and $b$ is any of the other four, because $\mathbb{Q}(a) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b) \not \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $x^5 - 1$ is not irreducible.

Answer (score 5):

A stronger, perhaps simpler, assertion is true here, namely, that inside *any* algebraically closed field $K\supset\mathbb Q$, for distinct roots $\alpha,\beta$ of $x^5-15=0$, $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\not=\mathbb Q(\beta)$.

By Eisenstein's criterion and Gauss' lemma, for example, $x^5-15$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$, so adjoining any single root (inside the extension $K$) generates a degree-five field.

Any two (distinct) roots $\alpha,\beta$ have ratio $\alpha/\beta$ that is a fifth root of unity (not $=1$). A separate discussion of roots of unity tells us that a fifth root of unity generates a degree-four extension of $\mathbb Q$. The multiplicativity of degrees in towers (and coprimality of $5$ and $4$) shows that $\mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta)$ is degree $20$ over $\mathbb Q$. Etc.

Comment: It is a nice proof, but you haven't actually proved a stronger result since the $K = \mathbb{C}$ case allows you to conclude that the statement holds for the splitting field of $x^5 - 15$, hence for any superfield of $\mathbb{Q}$ where $x^5 - 15$ splits completely.

Comment: @MarkSaving, well, yes, we do know that all "abstract" splitting fields are isomorphic, and so on. I was just thinking that we do not need to use algebraic closure of $\mathbb C$... although, sure, we do know it, and so on. Maybe not "stronger", but, rather, "independent of facts about $\mathbb C$ and imbeddings into it"? In my own arc, once I realized that there was no compulsion to imbed alg extensions of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb C$, lots of alg no th became much clearer. :)

Comment: +1. I try to avoid $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C} $ as much as possible. We can elaborate your argument by considering the quotient $K=\mathbb{Q} [x] /(x^5-15)$ and show that it contains one root of $x^5-15$ and not any other. The interesting part is that one can't say which root lies in $K$ and which one doesn't because from point of view of algebra all these roots are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

$x^5 - 15$ has 5 distinct roots since it is relatively prime with its derivative. It has exactly 1 real root, since $f(x) = x^5$ is a strictly increasing continuous function and $0^5 < 15 < 15^5$, so there is a root by the intermediate value theorem.

Let $a$ be the real root, and let $b$ be one of the four roots which is not real. Then $\mathbb{Q}(a) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $b \notin \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $b \notin \mathbb{Q}(a)$.

Therefore, we see that $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ contains only 1 root of $x^5 - 15$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(b) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(a)$ as rings for any other root $b$, this means that each $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ contains only 1 root of $x^5 - 15$. So for no two distinct roots $a, b$ is $a \in \mathbb{Q}(b)$. Thus, for any two distinct roots $a, b$, we have $\mathbb{Q}(a) \neq \mathbb{Q}(b)$.

Comment: @Arthur I misread it as asking to show existence of $a, b$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(a) \neq \mathbb{Q}(b)$. I have modified the proof appropriately.

Comment: Interesting repair, and reduction to the real-versus-complex case!

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks! That said, I think your proof is nicer as it's purely algebraic.

Comment: Nice. However, as written, your proof looks like it only requires knowing that  $\mathbb{Q}(a) \cong \mathbb{Q}(b)$. But it's more. It's that for any isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b)$, any root of $x^5 - 15$ lying in $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ must be mapped to by a root of $x^5 - 15$.

Comment: @DionelJaime This is clearly true since if $f$ is a ring homomorphism then $f(c^5 - 15) = f(c)^5 - 15$.